# Hacer que webgrid no tenga paginado, muestre todo en una sola pagina

Tags: mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4

solicito de su apoyo trabajamos en un webgrid, y todo es funcional, pero quisiera saber como desplegar la información del grid sin que me lo divida en paginas.

Este es mi codigo, funciona bien, pero pretendo hacer que el listado aparezca completo:

```
<h1>Tutorados Asignados</h1>
<div class="well">
@using (Html.BeginForm("index", null, FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div style="margin-top:17px;">
        @{
            var grid = new WebGrid(
                        canPage: true,
                        rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize,
                        canSort: true,
                        ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");

            grid.Bind(Model.Content, rowCount: Model.TotalRecords, autoSortAndPage: false);
            grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);

            @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" },   // id for ajaxUpdateContainerId parameter
            fillEmptyRows: false,
            tableStyle: "table table-striped table-bordered",
            mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
            columns: grid.Columns(
              grid.Column("Id", "Id"),
              grid.Column("cve_grupo", "Grupo", style: "col-lg-1"),
              grid.Column("nombres", "Nombre(s)", style: "col-lg-2"),
              grid.Column("ape_pat", "Paterno", style: "col-lg-2"),
              grid.Column("ape_mat", "Materno", style: "col-lg-2"),
              grid.Column("generacion", "Generación", style: "col-lg-1"),
              grid.Column("sem_actual", "Semestre", style: "col-lg-1"),
              grid.Column("edo", "SIES", style: "col-lg-1"),
              grid.Column("regular", "Situación", style: "col-lg-1"),
                 grid.Column(header: "", canSort: false, style: "action",
                   format: @<text>
                            @Html.Raw("<a class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' href='/GruposSIESAsignados/BorraTutor/" + item.id + "' id='" + item.id + "' title='Ver tutorias del Tutor'> <span class='mdi mdi-delete-forever'> </span> </a>")
                </text>)

       ));
        }
    </div>
}
```

Muchas gracias...

Comment: Sucede que la paginación existe por varios motivos, siendo uno de ellos el rendimiento, ¿estás seguro que quieres mostrar todos los resultados de una sola vez?

Comment: Saludos, si, lo que pasa es que la cantidad a mostrar siempre será entre 10 y 30 lineas no más... así que queremos mostrar todo el listado completo. Pero no se como indicarle al webgrid omita la paginación y muestre el listado completo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ojo a la propiedad: `rowsPerPage`, en tu caso debería ir como la cantidad total de elementos. Por efectos de practicidad, le he asignado: `rowsPerPage: 50`

Aquí tu código:

```
<h1>Tutorados Asignados</h1>
<div class="well">
@using (Html.BeginForm("index", null, FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div style="margin-top:17px;">
        @{
            var grid = new WebGrid(
                        canPage: true,
                        rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize,
                        canSort: true,
                        ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid",
                        rowsPerPage: 50);

            grid.Bind(Model.Content, rowCount: Model.TotalRecords, autoSortAndPage: false);
            grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);

            @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" },   // id for ajaxUpdateContainerId parameter
            fillEmptyRows: false,
            tableStyle: "table table-striped table-bordered",
            mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
            columns: grid.Columns(
              grid.Column("Id", "Id"),
              grid.Column("cve_grupo", "Grupo", style: "col-lg-1"),
              grid.Column("nombres", "Nombre(s)", style: "col-lg-2"),
              grid.Column("ape_pat", "Paterno", style: "col-lg-2"),
              grid.Column("ape_mat", "Materno", style: "col-lg-2"),
              grid.Column("generacion", "Generación", style: "col-lg-1"),
              grid.Column("sem_actual", "Semestre", style: "col-lg-1"),
              grid.Column("edo", "SIES", style: "col-lg-1"),
              grid.Column("regular", "Situación", style: "col-lg-1"),
                 grid.Column(header: "", canSort: false, style: "action",
                   format: @<text>
                            @Html.Raw("<a class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' href='/GruposSIESAsignados/BorraTutor/" + item.id + "' id='" + item.id + "' title='Ver tutorias del Tutor'> <span class='mdi mdi-delete-forever'> </span> </a>")
                </text>)

       ));
        }
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Gracias fredyfx, solucionado.